# Getting 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied Error for ASP.Net website

Tags: c#, asp.net

We recently created one Development Server and moved the codes to it from Production Server. In Dev server Authentication is being applied through OpenAM Single Sign On. But in Production it's not, i.e Authentication is Forms authentication. All other applications of Dev Server inside the particular website are working except for one application which is giving me this error:

```
403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.
```

For Example:

https://dev.Example.org/Result/Old.asp is working but https://dev.Example.org/Result/New.asp is giving 403 Forbidden Error.

I tried several steps mentioned in previous blogs in forum but nothing worked:

I checked the App Pools setting in IIS and made sure Application is referring to correct App Pool, checked Web.config to see if `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests` is set to True or not. It didn't work. It's strange other application inside same website is working and this one is giving 403 error.

Any idea would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: are all the necessary windows features enabled? Are their folder permissions which could be preventing it from working?

Comment: Thanks for the answer user1666620. I checked, all the Windows Features are enabled. Also, Permissions is set to Everyone with all the access like Read, Write, Execute, Etc.

Comment: have you been able to reproduce the error on your dev environment by changing Authentication methods? Is there an error displayed in the event viewer which could indicate something? Could it be something to do with a permission setting? Under what identity is the application pool running?

Comment: I changed the Authentication to Basic Authentication disabling Anonymous Authentication just to make similar to Prod environment, it didn't work. I checked Error logs in C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\HTTPERR, it just lists the details from which port request coming, host name and Protocol details only. Application pool is running with "ApplicationPoolIdentity"

Comment: Can you try changing the application pool to run as an Administrator account?

Comment: @user1666620; How can I see this? I verified my Authentication is using this ApplicationPoolIdentity as default. One thing I noticed today is, I can go to this link https://dev.Example.org/Result/New.asp  without query string parameter, but if there is query string parameter in url that comes from previous page, I get 403 forbidden. For Example:  https://dev.Example.org/Result/New.asp?fullname=Sam%20Smith gives 403 forbidden but without query string https://dev.Example.org/Result/New.asp doesn't give 403 forbidden, but I need query string to show to show details. Any idea on this one?
Thanks

Comment: on IIS, go to Application Pools. Right click on the application pool the application is using and select "Advanced Settings". Where is says Identity, click on the "..." button and choose Custom Account, then use an Administrator account.

Comment: @user1666620 I tried using admin account as you suggested and restarted the iis Server after I changed. It didn't work.

Comment: Ok, I know you said you did this but check again: from Windows Features, go to Internet Information Services > World Wide Web Services > Application Development Features. Make sure the ASP.Net features have been enabled.
I know from experience that this can cause the error you are experiencing - has caught me out before.